# golang can not parse an item of json

Tags: go

I can't use golang to parse this json with server response:

```
{
"id": 1,
"description": "{\"uDes\":\"\",\"reDes\":[{\"des\":\"aaa,,request=<?xml version=“1.0“ encoding=“GBK“?><Req ver=“3.0“><HR version=“3.0“ cd=“0“><src><\\\\/src><license><\\\\/license><clientid>com.sample.xo<\\\\/clientid><ii>8603<\\\\/ii><im>46002910<\\\\/im><uuid>da032b2<\\\\/uuid><reqid>-21851<\\\\/reqid><smc>44:91<\\\\/smc><sdv>2.0.201501131131.a.r<\\\\/sdv><corv>V1.1.0r<\\\\/corv><\\\\/HDR><DRR nettype=“LTE“ inftype=“1“><mc>460<\\\\/cc><mnc>00<\\\\/mnc><lac>34809<\\\\/lac><cellid>8842241<\\\\/cellid><signal>-69<\\\\/signal><\\\\/DRR><\\\\/Cell_Req>&retype=3&timestamp=1469550331136\"}]}"
}
```

please note the key 'description' has a lot of illegal character.I just want to get and store it as a string into our database.
the go code fragment following:

```
import (
   "fmt"
   "net/http"
   "encoding/json"
)
var p := fmt.Println
type DataSlice struct{
     Id int
     Destription string
}
func main() {
    p("Start fetching data..")
    resp,err := http.Get("http://127.0.0.1/pis")
    if err != nil{
    //handle error
       p(err)
    }else{
       defer resp.Body.Close()
       var jsonInst DataSlice
       p("Start decode json body..")
       err := json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&jsonInst)
       if err != nil {
         panic(err)
       }else{
         //do insert here
       }
    }
}
```

this code execute fine,but the description value is empty.please help me to resolve this problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You have a typo `Destription != Description`.

Comment: Thank u Jim..I haven't check this mapping key. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that you have a typo - `Destription` instead of `Description` in your `DataSlice` struct.  See the following example in PlayGround that successfully parses your JSON blob - https://play.golang.org/p/CeoCH2SJXh:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

var input = `{
"id": 1,
"description": "{\"uDes\":\"\",\"reDes\":[{\"des\":\"aaa,,request=<?xml version=“1.0“ encoding=“GBK“?><Req ver=“3.0“><HR version=“3.0“ cd=“0“><src><\\\\/src><license><\\\\/license><clientid>com.sample.xo<\\\\/clientid><ii>8603<\\\\/ii><im>46002910<\\\\/im><uuid>da032b2<\\\\/uuid><reqid>-21851<\\\\/reqid><smc>44:91<\\\\/smc><sdv>2.0.201501131131.a.r<\\\\/sdv><corv>V1.1.0r<\\\\/corv><\\\\/HDR><DRR nettype=“LTE“ inftype=“1“><mc>460<\\\\/cc><mnc>00<\\\\/mnc><lac>34809<\\\\/lac><cellid>8842241<\\\\/cellid><signal>-69<\\\\/signal><\\\\/DRR><\\\\/Cell_Req>&retype=3&timestamp=1469550331136\"}]}"
}`

var p = fmt.Println

type DataSlice struct {
    Id          int
    Description string
}

func main() {
    var inst DataSlice
    p("Start decode json body..")
    err := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(input)).Decode(&inst)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", inst)
}
```

Output:

```
Start decode json body..

main.DataSlice{Id:1, Description:"{\"uDes\":\"\",\"reDes\":[{\"des\":\"aaa,,request=<?xml version=“1.0“ encoding=“GBK“?><Req ver=“3.0“><HR version=“3.0“ cd=“0“><src><\\\\/src><license><\\\\/license><clientid>com.sample.xo<\\\\/clientid><ii>8603<\\\\/ii><im>46002910<\\\\/im><uuid>da032b2<\\\\/uuid><reqid>-21851<\\\\/reqid><smc>44:91<\\\\/smc><sdv>2.0.201501131131.a.r<\\\\/sdv><corv>V1.1.0r<\\\\/corv><\\\\/HDR><DRR nettype=“LTE“ inftype=“1“><mc>460<\\\\/cc><mnc>00<\\\\/mnc><lac>34809<\\\\/lac><cellid>8842241<\\\\/cellid><signal>-69<\\\\/signal><\\\\/DRR><\\\\/Cell_Req>&retype=3&timestamp=1469550331136\"}]}"}
```